# Error using @httpGet annotation in node express

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am getting the error

> Error TS1241: Unable to resolve signature of method decorator when called as an expression.' when I use the annotation '@httpGet('/product')

I imported the following packages:

```
"express": "^4.17.1",
"inversify": "^5.0.1",
"inversify-express-utils": "^6.3.2"
```

and my code is:

```
import { controller, httpGet, request, response } from "inversify-express-utils";
import { Request, Response } from "express";

@controller("")
export class ProductController implements IProductController {

    @httpGet('/product')
    async get(@request() req: Request, @response() res: Response) {

        ....
    }
}
```

Has anyone had the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

The controller annotation needs to be the name of the route, and the `get` annotation requires you to specify the query parameters or just `/` if you have none. Also try using the interfaces.Controller as a base class. For example, try the following code

```
import { interfaces, controller, httpGet, request, response } from "inversify-express-utils";
import { Request, Response } from "express";

@controller("/product")
export class ProductController implements interfaces.Controller {

    @httpGet('/')
    async get(@request() req: Request, @response() res: Response) { ... }

    @httpGet('/:productId')
    async get(@request() req: Request, @response() res: Response) { ... }
}
```